# Searching repositories for files with forbidden strings

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, regex, file-system

I wrote a small tool for searching git repositories for forbidden strings that I don't want to commit publicly. It's still something basic but it does the job.

The project contains three files.

`config.py` - this is the file where I store the *secrects* like which directories to scan and which strings to look for in a long regex (here redacted). This is commited to a VSTS repository because they are private.

```
import re

paths = [
        "c:\\..",
        "c:\\.."
    ]

re_forbidden = re.compile(r"(class)")
```

`main.py` - this is the core file. It uses `os.walk` to list all files and directories. Not all directories and files are processed. Paths that don't get commited like `.git` or `bin` and files like `dll` are skipped. Paths and the `re_forbitten` regex are imported from the above `config.py`. When found something suspicious then it just outputs the path of the affected file.

```
import os
import time
import itertools
import shutil
import re
import importlib.util
config_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("config", "c:\\home\\projects\\classified\\python\\sanipyzer\\config.py")
config = importlib.util.module_from_spec(config_spec)
config_spec.loader.exec_module(config)
from pprint import pprint

ignore_dirs = [".git", "bin", "obj", ".vs"]
ignore_files = ["dll", "exe", "pdb", "map"]

def format_filemtime(path):
    filemtime = os.path.getmtime(path)
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.gmtime(filemtime))

def ignore_dir(dirpath):
    for dir in ignore_dirs:
        pattern = r"\\" + re.escape(dir) + r"(\\|$)"
        if re.search(pattern, dirpath):
            return True
    return False

def ignore_file(file_name):
    for ext in ignore_files:
        pattern = r"\." + ext + "$"
        if re.search(pattern, file_name):
            return True
    return False


def sanitize(path):    

    start = time.perf_counter()

    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        if ignore_dir(dirpath):
            continue
        searchable_filenames = [filename for filename in filenames if not ignore_file(filename)]
        for filename in searchable_filenames:
            full_name = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)

            # without 'ignore' it throws for some files the UnicodeDecodeError 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte XXX in position XXX: invalid start byte
            with open(full_name, 'r', encoding="utf8", errors="ignore") as searchable:
                text = searchable.read()
                if config.re_forbidden.search(text):
                    pprint(full_name)

    end = time.perf_counter()
    elapsed = round(end - start,2)
    print(f"elapsed: {elapsed} sec")

# --- --- ---

def main():    
    for path in config.paths:
        sanitize(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`test.py` - this file is a very simple unittest. It tests the two *ignore* methods.

```
import unittest

from main import ignore_dir
from main import ignore_file

class MainTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_ignore_dir(self):
        self.assertTrue(ignore_dir("c:\\temp\\.git"))
        self.assertTrue(ignore_dir("c:\\temp\\.git\\abc"))

    def test_ignore_file(self):
        self.assertTrue(ignore_file("c:\\temp\\project\\program.dll"))
        self.assertFalse(ignore_file("c:\\temp\\project\\program.cs"))
        # tests the test
        #self.assertTrue(ignore_file("c:\\temp\\project\\program.cs"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # use False to avoid the traceback "Exception has occurred: SystemExit"
    unittest.main(exit=False)
```

What do you think of it? Is this an acceptable solution or are there still many [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) mistakes? I wasn't sure about the two `ignore` lists whether they are `const` and should be UPPER_CASE or are they just simple variables?

Comment: Have you considered turning this into a [git pre-commit hook](https://githooks.com)? Then the rules would be automatically enforced (unless you commit with the `--no-verify` option).  Also, you can use `diff --cached` to only consider the content that changed.

Comment: @200_success yeah, thanks! I've discovered it just after I was done with the refactoring after receiving the review. I mentioned it in the last paragraph in my self-answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is a good code. However, I have a few remarks. Note: I am assuming that the code works perfectly as it should and will comment only on the style. Also, I assume that you are an experienced programmer and hence will not be explaining the basics, although if something is not clear please let me know.

## Configuration

You might want to keep the real paths separate to a configuration script. I'd advice you to create a [*.cfg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) file that would store all the configuration data. I can imagine this being used on different machines with different paths each. I don't think you would like to allow users to modify the code, it is better to give them config file.

In case you would like to keep the configuration as it is, I'd encourage to move the lists to config.py and name (as you mentioned) in UPPER_CASE. Additionally, you might also want to encapsulate them in a functions like this:

```
def get_ignored_dirs():
    return ignored_dirs
```

This allows to keep the API of config.py constant regardless on what you decide to do with inners of the configuration.

Lastly, you might consider moving your functions like `ignore_dir` to separate file (e.g. files_utils.py) and treat is as a proxy to your configuration.

## Method naming

In general I tend do explicitly say that some function returns boolean value by sticking `is` at the beginning. For example, it is clear (from the code) that your function `ignore_dir` checks if the directory should be ignored. This is however, not clear from the name, one might think that this function ignores some directory. I'd suggest to change the name to `is_ignored_dir` or something similar. The same goes for `ignore_file`.

## Separation of concerns and responsibilities

It seems for me that your `sanitize` function is not very SRP-like. Inside, you do many things including deciding whether to ignore a directory (or file), read the file and count time. I'd suggest dividing those responsibilities to more than one function. You might notice that if you try to do a unit test for this function, in reality it will be a e2e test.

Below, an example of what you can fix it.

```
def measured(func):
    def wrapper(path):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        func(path)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed = round(end - start,2)
        print(f"elapsed: {elapsed} sec")
    return wrapper

def searchable_files_from_list(filenames):
    for filename in filenames:
        if not is_ignore_file(filename):
            yield filename

def searchable_files_containing_forbidden_text(filenames):
    for filename in searchable_files_from_list(filenames):
        full_name = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        if contains_forbidden_text(full_name):
            yield full_name

def contains_forbidden_text(filename):
    with open(full_name, 'r', encoding="utf8", errors="ignore") as searchable:
    text = searchable.read()
    if config.re_forbidden.search(text):
        return True
    return False

def files_to_sanitize(path):
    for (dirpath,dirname,filenames) in os.walk(path):
        if is_ignored_dir(dirpath):
            continue
        for file in searchable_files_containing_forbidden_text(filenames):
            yield file

@measured
def print_files_to_sanitize(path):
    for file in files_to_sanitize(path):
        pprint(file)
```

**Explanation:**

Now, all of your methods can be separately unit tested and validated. Let's take look at each function at a time, starting with the last one.

*print_files_to_sanitize* 
This is what is left from your `sanitize` function. After the refactoring it become apparent that the function does not sanitize anything, it just prints a file name. This fact wasn't so clear before because of many things happening.

I've added a decorator to the function - this is a very common practice for measuring time of the method (you might want to generalize this by using [*args and **kw](https://medium.com/pythonhive/python-decorator-to-measure-the-execution-time-of-methods-fa04cb6bb36d)).

*files_to_sanitize* is a generator that should give you all of the files that should be sanitized. It iterates through your catalogs ignoring some directories and getting the files from a second generator.

*searchable_files_containing_forbidden_text* Given a list of files it iterates over those which have a good file name (given by `searchable_files_from_list` function) and if such file contains a forbidden text it bubbles it up.

Comment: Yes, I tested it with all my repositories and also with one that intentionally contained some illegal strings and after some initial problems it does its job well now. You're right, I'm not a complete beginner, just in python but I'll figure the new stuff out (and there are few things that I haven't seen yet) - but there are some links ;-). This is great review!

Answer (score 2):

I've refactored this and splitted the single method into multiple smaller ones. While reading about the `*.cfg` there was a link to `json` so I used this for the config. Now I have two of them: a local one, with only a single path:

```js
{
    "private_config_path":"c:\\home\\projects\\classified\\python\\sanipyzer\\config.json"
}
```

and a *secret* one with all the rules:

```js
{
    "scan_dirs": [
        "c:\\..",        
    ],
    "ignore_dirs": [
        ".git",
        "bin",
        "obj",
        ".vs"
    ],
    "ignore_files": [
        "dll",
        "exe",
        "pdb",
        "map"
    ],
    "forbidden_pattern": "..."
}
```

I've read about the `*args` and `**kwargs` and moved the stopwatch to a decorator (this is really cool and I already miss it in C#). This is now a part of my `reusable.py`.

```
import time

def log_elapsed(func):
    def measure(*args, **kw):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        func(*args, **kw)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed = round(end - start, 2)
        print(f"'{func.__name__}' elapsed: {elapsed} sec")
    return measure
```

The `main.py` has grown a little bit with its multiple functions but there are no global variables anymore and all values are passed via parameters. I'm not sure this is the best way and looks somehow verbose but I'll keep reading and the next script will be better. At the time of writing it I still don't know anything about classes in python.

```
import os
import time
import itertools
import shutil
import re
import json
import importlib.util
from pprint import pprint

from reusable import log_elapsed

def format_filemtime(path):
    filemtime = os.path.getmtime(path)
    return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.gmtime(filemtime))

def is_ignored_dir(dirpath, ignore_dirs):
    for dir in ignore_dirs:
        pattern = r"\\" + re.escape(dir) + r"(\\|$)"
        if re.search(pattern, dirpath):
            return True
    return False

def is_ignored_file(file_name, ignore_files):
    for ext in ignore_files:
        pattern = r"\." + ext + "$"
        if re.search(pattern, file_name):
            return True
    return False

def contains_forbidden_text(filename, re_forbidden):
    with open(filename, encoding="utf8", errors="ignore") as searchable:
        text = searchable.read()
        return True if re_forbidden.search(text) else False

def files_containing_forbidden_text(dirpath, filenames, re_forbidden):
    for filename in filenames:
        full_name = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        if contains_forbidden_text(full_name, re_forbidden):
            yield filename

def searchable_files(filenames, ignore_files):
    for filename in filenames:
        if not is_ignored_file(filename, ignore_files):
            yield filename

def files_to_sanitize(path, ignore_dirs, ignore_files, re_forbidden):    
    for (dirpath, dirname, filenames) in os.walk(path):
        if is_ignored_dir(dirpath, ignore_dirs):
            continue
        filenames = searchable_files(filenames, ignore_files)
        filenames = files_containing_forbidden_text(dirpath, filenames, re_forbidden)
        for filename in filenames:
            full_name = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            yield full_name

def load_config():
    with open("config.json", "r") as f:
       return json.load(f)

def load_rules(path):
    with open(path, "r") as f:
       return json.load(f)

# --- --- ---

@log_elapsed
def main():    

    config = load_config()
    rules = load_rules(config["private_config_path"])

    re_forbidden = re.compile(rules["forbidden_pattern"])

    for path in rules["scan_dirs"]:
        for filename in files_to_sanitize(path, rules["ignore_dirs"], rules["ignore_files"], re_forbidden):
            pprint(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the next step I will use this script (with small changes) as a [Git Hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for preventing commits when there are files that need to be sanitized first. (I hadn't known about this trick when I started with it thus the list of directories to scan)